# parent an object to a bone in python

Tags: python, bones, parent

I'm trying to parent an object to a bone in python without using operator
So I did this :

```
object = bpy.data.objects['object']
armature = bpy.data.objects['Armature']
bone = armature.pose.bones['bone']

object.parent = armature 
object.parent_bone = bone.name
object.matrix_parent_inverse = bone.matrix_local.inverted()
```

[image]

the object is on the tail of the bone it must be on the head
What should I do?

Comment: Would be nice to know the answer to this. It's quite a simple concept, but appears to be impossible to do in Blener??

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (2.91), solved this way (seems to work):

```
    mpi = empty.matrix_parent_inverse
    ti = mathutils.Matrix.Translation([0, bone.length, 0]).inverted()
    empty.matrix_parent_inverse = mpi @ ti
```

`empty` is the object, I'm currently placing a sphere, so I'm not watching out for rotations, you may require some.

A couple of answers were useful:

- https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/139180/1155
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27011/1155

Answer (score 2):

I have been having a similar problem and using `bone.length` only works if the head of the bone is on the origin.

A more general solution is to find the vector from the tail back to the head and add that to the `parent_matrix_inverted`.

This function appears to work for bones regardless of their orientation. Note the rig must be in pose mode for this work otherwise `rig.pose.bones` will be empty.

```
def parentBone(rig, boneName, geo):
    bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().update()
    bone = rig.pose.bones[boneName]

    geo.parent=rig
    geo.parent_type = "BONE"
    geo.parent_bone = boneName

    vec = bone.head - bone.tail
    trans = mathutils.Matrix.Translation(vec)
    geo.matrix_parent_inverse = bone.matrix.inverted() @ trans
```