# Weird Offset when Using a parenting bone script

Tags: python, rigging

there are two cubes on the same spot

[image: two cubes on the same spot]

but

When I use this(similar might not work if you try)

```
def parent_set(object, armature, bone):
    object.parent = armature
    object.parent_bone = bone
    object.parent_type = 'BONE'


objj = bpy.data.objects
parent_set(objj['object'], objj['Armature'], 'bone')
```

it does something like this

[image: Weird offset]

How can i fix this

Comment: batFINGER the armature is in the picture it looks like it parents it to the head but it isn't consistent it sometimes puts it on the some "random" spot

Comment: Try  my answer on same [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112776/parent-object-to-a-bone-and-object-becomes-offsets-how-do-i-prevent-object-from) you gleaned your question code.

Comment: i got the this version of the code from your answer

Comment: so i found something that when i apply the transforms it puts it on the head

Comment: but it kinda brokes my code

Comment: To me it looks like the accepted answer, which pointed out the error in my first answer version (which was parenting to head) After which added  a long winded edit on getting different results. The "random" offset you are seeing is quite likely the basis matrix of the cube.

Comment: so how can i fix it btw my original code uses `def parent_set(object, armature, bone):
    object.parent = armature
    object.parent_bone = bone
    object.parent_type = 'BONE'
objj = bpy.data.objects
    parent_set(objj[str(1+i)+'_obj'], objj['Armature_pyhs'], str(1+i)+'_bone')`

Comment: hmmmm i changed the post to "original form with some grammar fixes" and i tried your script and it did the similar thing

Comment: Apologies, was missing the wood from the trees, will edit prior answer.

Comment: so i botched it instead i just changed location of them (the objects that are parented to the bones) and added a different script that parent the objects to the with Automatic Weights