# How to parent an object to the tail of a bone in python (blender 2.90)

Tags: bones, parent

I'm trying to create a bone and parent an empty to its tail, and constrain the bone to point toward the camera.
See this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/W0nuhdFX).
I've figured out how to create the bone and even create the constraint, but don't know how to parent the focus object (the empty) to the bone's tail.

I've read the [older SO question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31017/parent-an-object-to-a-bone-in-python) on this, but that code doesn't work anymore since it's 2.7-based.

Here's my code so far:

```
def link_object(object):
  view_layer = bpy.context.view_layer
  view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection.objects.link(object)

armature = bpy.data.armatures.new('Armature')
armature_object = bpy.data.objects.new('Armature', armature)
link_object(armature_object)
# Make it active
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = armature_object

# Enter edit mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT', toggle=False)
# Add a bone
bone = armature_object.data.edit_bones.new('focusBone')
bone.head=(0,0,0)
bone.tail=(0,0,1)
# ...
#Exit armature editing; this allows bones to be used in Pose/Object modes
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT', toggle=False)

# Create constraint: bone looks at camera
constraint = bpy.context.object.pose.bones['focusBone'].constraints.new('DAMPED_TRACK')
camera=bpy.data.objects['Camera']
constraint.target=camera

# Create the empty to serve as a focus target
focus_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('focusObj', None)
focus_obj.location=(0,0,1)
link_object(focus_obj)

# QUESTION: how to parent the focus_obj to the tail of the bone?
```

Comment: Please post any relevant  code into question.  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112776/parent-object-to-a-bone-and-object-becomes-offsets-how-do-i-prevent-object-from